# GDAL Installation Failing on CentOs Error: config.status: error: invalid argument: `src/proj_config.h'

Tags: python, gdal, docker, centos

I need a version of GDAL > 3 so I am installing from source and having an issue, this is the error I am getting.

```
make[2]: Leaving directory `/var/task'
12.28 cd .. && /bin/sh ./config.status src/proj_config.h
12.44 config.status: error: invalid argument: `src/proj_config.h'
12.44 make[1]: *** [stamp-h1] Error 1
12.44 make[1]: Leaving directory `/var/task/src'
12.45 make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

Here is my Dokerfile

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.9

COPY . ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}

RUN yum update -y && yum install wget -y && \
    yum clean all && yum install xz -y && \
    yum install gzip -y && \
    yum groups mark install "Development Tools" -y && \
    yum groups mark convert "Development Tools" -y && \
    yum groupinstall "Development Tools" -y && \
    yum install unzip -y

RUN yum install gcc-c++.x86_64 cpp.x86_64 sqlite-devel.x86_64 libtiff.x86_64 cmake3.x86_64 tar.x86_64 -y

RUN wget https://download.osgeo.org/proj/proj-6.1.1.tar.gz

RUN tar -zxf proj-6.1.1.tar.gz

RUN unzip -o ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}/proj-datumgrid-1.7.zip -d ./proj-6.1.1/data/

RUN ./proj-6.1.1/configure --disable-dependency-tracking --prefix=/export/apps/proj/proj-6.1.1 && \
    make -j4 && \
    mkdir -p /export/apps/proj/proj-6.1.1 && \
    make install

RUN chown -R root:root /export/apps/proj/proj-6.1.1

ENV PROJ_LIB="/export/apps/proj/proj-6.1.1"

RUN wget https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/releases/download/v3.2.1/gdal-3.2.1.tar.gz

RUN tar -zxf gdal-3.2.1.tar.gz

RUN ./gdal-3.2.1/configure --disable-dependency-tracking  --prefix=/export/apps/gdal/gdal-3.2.1 --with-proj=/export/apps/proj/proj-6.1.1 --with-python=/usr/bin/python && \
    make -j4 && \
    mkdir -p /export/apps/gdal/gdal-3.2.1 && \
    make install

RUN chown -R root:root /export/apps/gdal/gdal-3.2.1

RUN which gdalinfo; gdalinfo --version

RUN pip install gdal==3.2.1 Fiona==1.8.21 shapely geopandas

CMD ["lambda_function.lambda_handler"]
```